# SMTP connection refused after 354 only from web server deployed on same machine as smtp postfix

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I have a weird problem. My SMTP server is deployed on linux host (postfix/dovecot). I have a Spring MVC + Tomcat based web application. If I connect to the SMTP server on Lunix server (Centos) from my local macbook, the messages are sent fine. However, when I deployed the web app on Tomcat 7 (with trusted CA cert SSL) on the Linux system, it is giving me a Connection refused exception AFTER receiving 354 from the server. I have also generated the open ssl certificate for the smtp and added to trusted certificate in the jdk/jre/lib/security/cacert. I have tried both smtp and smtps on both macbook and linux servers. On dev, both works. On linux(prod), both fails. Please note that in both dev and prod, it is able to authenticate and login. It is only after '354 End data with .' response from SMTP, the behaviour of dev and prod differ.

From my spring appServerContext.xml:-

```
            <property name="host" value="${linux.host}" />
            <property name="port" value="${linux_ssl.port}" />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
            <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.connectiontimeout">5000</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.sendpartial">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.userset">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.isSecure">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.requiresAuthentication">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.ssl.trust">*</prop> -->
        </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

SMTP debugging from dev log :

```
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
..
From: Test User <testuser@mydomain.com>
To: princess_yvonne@gmail.com
Message-ID: <1833254786.2.1468329021927.JavaMail.local@Yvonne-Koks-MacBook-  Pro.local>
Subject: Acknowledgement
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

From prod (both smtp and smtps fails at the same place with the same error)

```
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
DEBUG SMTP: IOException while sending, closing, THROW:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at        java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at     
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625) at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160) at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254) at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:168) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper$1.getInputStream(MimeMessageHelper.java:1093) at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:305) at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485) at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:865) at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:462) at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103) at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889) at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317) at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485) at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:865) at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:462) at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103) at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889) at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317) at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485) at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1773) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:433) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
```

I have exhaustively searched for the exact issue. Although, there are example of ConnectionRefused, none that came right after 354 when being on the same box as the smtp server came to my notice.

Highly appreciate your help, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the [socket factory stuff, you don't need it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Are you using a URLDataSource for part of the content of the message you're sending?  The connection is being dropped when JavaMail tries to access part of the content of your message, which requires an https connection to some server.  It's the https connection that's being dropped, causing the SMTP connection to be dropped.

Comment: You are indeed correct @Bill Shannon, a 100% correct. I changed that URLResource to ServletContextResource and it started working. You saved my week and made my day. Thank you so much. God bless!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was rightly pointed by @bill-shannon. It was indeed a URLResource of a png image that was the problem. I changed it to be a ServletContextResource and it is working.
Hopefully, someone finds this useful and saves frustration and time.
Special thanks to Bill Shannon for nailing it so correctly!!!